# Regex to find space at or before the n-th character of a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find the space character at or before the nth character of a string.

Example, assuming that n is 20: in the string

```
 Find one space in the right place
^         ^       ^ ^
0         10      M 20
```

the *h* is in the 20th position, int this case I need to find the first space before the 20th position, the one before the word "the" in 18th position, just over the **M**.

I can find the nth character using positive lookbehinds like

```
(?<=.{80}).
```

**but then I need to go back until I find the first space character** and I don't know how.

I'm using notepad++ which doesn't support variable length lookbehinds, if possible I'd like an answer allowing me to use the regex also in notepad++. Thanks.

Comment: Why regex? Just linear scan should work, and even faster.

Comment: Because I am not using a programming language

Comment: Regex to find.. What do you mean by finding? Do you want the position of the last space before the 20th character?

Comment: I need it for replacement purpose, I'm going to replace that space with something else, using notepad++, so I just need the regex to work in the search box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex (inside but excluding quotes):

```
"^.{1,19} "
```

Note the space at the end.

I have tested this with Notepad++ 6.1.5 (the latest version at time of posting). According to the [feature list](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features.html), the regex is PCRE compatible (look-behind works, but fixed width only). The regex above doesn't work on an older version I current have (Notepad++ 5.9).

Since you need to replace the space with something else, you may want to use capturing group to preserve the text and replace only the space (inside but excluding quotes):

```
"^(.{1,19}) " (Find)
"\1replace_space" (Replace)
```

Note: The regex will search for the space before or at the 20th character. If you want the space to be strictly before 20th character, change 19 to 18.

Comment: For `n = 20` I believe you should use `^.{1,18}(\s)` pattern

Comment: I just need the space, not all the string

Comment: @Gabber: If the space is at the 20th character, will the matched space be that character, or some space before it?

Comment: @Ωmega: You are probably right (so I'm asking for clarification from the OP about the border case). Either way, I need to modify the regex to either 19 or 18. I'd prefer the space over `\s`, though.

Comment: This works with {1,19}, this is a simple, good solution, sorry I didn't think of that myself :)

Comment: @Gabber - Using `^.{1,19} ` you will match space at poistion 20 or before, not before 20...

Comment: You are right, i'll edit the question matching my real needs, sorry for the mistake

Comment: This solution is great but it breaks for a word longer than max characters (19 in your answer). For a solution that would either split the string on a space if it is present or on any character otherwise, you could use this regex `(^[^ ]{20})?(?(1)|^.{1,20} )`. https://regex101.com/r/RkHel3/1

Comment: @UlysseBN: This comes down to the specific requirement, and there's no mention of such case in the question. Personally, I find truncating a word without sign of doing so may result in meaningless word or [worse](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html)

Comment: @nhahtdh I find that the link you gave has no relation to the issue discussed here. If you want to truncate a work you can do it explicitly, using some keys to indicate what you are doing to your user. I don't think it is relevant to include my comment in your answer, but I find that it may serve some. It allowed me to make this utility: https://gist.github.com/BuonOmo/c9d89653e111b7fc333087a1d9e6ceb7

Answer (score -1):

For **n = 20**, use regex `(\s)\S*.(?<=^.{20})`